# Angular2 boolean Input parameter not working

Tags: angular, input, components

In my Planning component I have the following directive where selectedPerson is an object on the service and showModal is a local boolean parameter in the Planning component:

```
<person-popup [person]="planningService.selectedPerson" [show]="showModal"></person-popup>
```

The PersonPopop component has the following simple structure:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Counselor } from '../entities/counselor';
import { Person } from '../entities/person';
import { Request } from '../entities/request';


@Component({
    selector: 'person-popup',
    templateUrl: './person-popup.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./person-popup.component.css']
})


export class PersonPopupComponent {

    @Input() person: Person;
    @Input() show: boolean;

    constructor() { }

    public displayCss() {
        return this.show ? "displayBlock" : "";
    }

    public toggleShow() {
        this.show = !this.show;
        console.log("toggleShow: ", this.show)
    }
}
```

The corresponding HTML view currently looks like this:

```
<p>{{show}}</p>
<p>{{person?.name}}</p>
<button (click)="toggleShow()">Show</button>

<div class="modal-background {{displayCss()}}" (click)="toggleShow()">
    <div class="modal-content animate">
        {{person?.name}}
    </div>
</div>
```

When the Planning component is initiated the show property is `null`.
Changes of selectedPerson are always propagated to the popup component but the same is NOT true for the showModal parameter.

When `showModal` is first set to `true` in the parent it is set to `true` in the child component.

The child component will then set its local `show` property to `false`.
After that it seems "the Input connection is lost" and all subsequent changes of `showModal` will not propagate to `show`.

Any suggestions on how to redesign this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update parent component property from child component in Angular 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41464871/update-parent-component-property-from-child-component-in-angular-2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use two way binding if you want to propagate the changes from child to parent :

```
export class PersonPopupComponent {

    @Input() person: Person;
    @Input() show: boolean;
    @Ouput() showChange= new EventEmitter<boolean>();

    constructor() { }

    public displayCss() {
        return this.show ? "displayBlock" : "";
    }

    public toggleShow() {
        this.show = !this.show;
        this.showChange.emit(this.show);
        console.log("toggleShow: ", this.show)
    }
}
```

then in parent :

```
<person-popup [person]="planningService.selectedPerson" [(show)]="showModal"></person-popup>
```

Comment: Thanks for quick answer! Some follow up questions to ensure I understand: 1) You mean all I need to do is to add paranthesis in directive binding, and add corresponding output parameter with emitter? 2) Is showChange a naming convention that will automatically match the two-way binding? 3) Isn't it confusing to emit a value and also set the local parameter? Wouldn't it be enough to just call this.showChange.emit(!this.show) and let it propagate the change to the Input parameter?

Comment: 1. yes. 2. the `Change` suffix is for using `[(bananaInABox)]` notation, but you can name it `showFoo`, for example, and use `[show]="someData" (showFoo)="doSomething($event)"` note that you ca do the same with `(showChange)="doSomething($event)"` ,banana in a box is not mandatory 3. Yes I guess it is possible.

Comment: For future readers I just add a reference to another post where two-way binding is performed with get/set methods. That makes it more verbose but it might be useful for some more complex cases. http://stackoverflow.com/a/39943368/1122813

Comment: @JakobLithner Just thought about your last "3." point. That might work, but only if you only rely on `@Input()` to get the value of that property. If you do that the two way binding becomes mandatory.