# Passing value from parent component to child component by reference

Tags: angular, pass-by-reference

I have 2 components: `parentComponent` and `childComponent`. In `parentComponent` I have a `FormGroup` type value as `parentForm` that is passed to `childComponent` via `@input`:

```js
export class parentComponent {
...

 parentForm: FormGroup;

....
}

export class childComponent {
...

 @Input()
 childForm :FormGroup; //The parentForm 

....
}
```

when I run these codes everything is ok and my `childComponent` recognize the `childForm` which is an input value from `parentComponent` but whenever I change some  properties in `parentForm` in `parentComponent` the `childComponent` is not able to be aware of these changes and when I debug my codes I see that the `childComponent` holds old input value and the changes is not updated in `childForm` in `childComponent`. now I seek to find a way to pass the reference of `parentForm` to solve my problem. because I think by this way any change in the `parentForm` will inform `childForm` immediately. 
I do not know how it is possible. (the version of Angular is 5.0.1)

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lk4j8t : I don't know what behavior you're looking for but I definitely get the changes to the `childForm` as well. Take a look at this stackblitz. You can try do `this.childForm.valueChanges` on your `childComponent` as well.

Answer (score 0):

In essence, this question is very related with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40260158/angular2-pass-by-reference-to-interact-between-components) and [this another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36246994/how-to-use-two-way-data-binding-between-components-in-angular-2).

To solve your problem, I suggest this approach:

- Fill an object using using your form group with the directive [NgModel](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel).
- Change `@Input() childForm :FormGroup` for `@Input() childForm : Object` being Object the filled object class using `NgModel`
- If `Object` is not a primitive value `string`,`boolean`, `num`, it will be passed by reference so you will have the updated value immediately.