# How to get parent/host of routed component

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Let's say we have ComponentA with that template:

```
 <div>
       <router-outlet></router-outlet>
 </div>
```

ComponentA has routeConfig to route to ComponentB.

How to get ComponentA from the routed componentB?

I tried to inject @Host to ComponentB but I get an exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The router adds components using `DynamicComponentLoader`. Such components have limited capabilities (no `@Input()` can be passed, `@Host()` can't be used).

You can use a shared service where `ComponentA` passes itself in and `ComponentB` can read the value.

A similar use case is explained here [Update parent component title from routed child component in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35975837/update-parent-component-title-from-routed-child-component-in-angular-2). The service doesn't have to be global. It can also be only shared between the parent and the child by adding it to `providers: [MySharedService]` of `ComponentA` instead of `bootstrap()` as shown in the linked answer.

Comment: Do you recommend to extend the RouterOutlet and manage a routing map to keep track of the routing changes?
I found it very difficult to know what is the components tree that was routed .

Comment: Extending `RouterOutlet` seems to be common practice, I haven't done it myself yet. Another way is to create a shared service, inject the `constructor(router:Router)` and subscribe to `router.subscribe(...)` to get notified about route changes.