# Change Header and Footer content on Route Change in Angular

Tags: angular

I am working on a simple Angular 2 app, and the routes I currently have are /login, /register, /home, and /profile.

On the main app component I have a `<header>` section, a `<content>` section, and a `<footer>` section.  I currently have the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in the `content` section, but would also like to *(sometimes)* change some content in the `header` and `footer` components when there is different content in the `content` section.

I have researched child routing (and plan to use for some of the routes in the content section), but I am not sure if that's the best approach, or even possible.  The child routing research I have done is from John Papa's Angular 2 course, and here is his example plunker: http://a2-first-look.azurewebsites.net/examples/router-child/plnkr.demo.html?bust=1463590738850

I have also explored subscribing to the router changes in the Header and Footer components, and render different html using `*ngIf`.  This approach seems to create a whole new service [SO 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35975837/update-parent-component-title-from-routed-child-component-in-angular-2), but this one seems a little more straightforward [SO 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33520043/angular-2-0-how-to-detect-route-change).  I am thinking I can just doing something with the native Router directive?

Any help or a point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could put this into your run block:

```
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (event, current, previous) {
    SomeService.header.dynamicText = 'Hello, World'
    SomeService.footer.dynamicText = 'Contact Us'
})
```

Of course, you'll have to pass `SomeService` to your run function, as well.

More on this handy little service [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route)