# In Dart Angular2 how can I update site header title based on active component?

Tags: angular, dart, angular-dart

I am building an Angular2/Dart application in which i like to change the page header title  based on active component.

I have found an answer which is based on rxjs Subject [as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35975837/update-parent-component-title-from-routed-child-component-in-angular-2).  How can I achieve the same without using rxjs Subject as Observable or more specifically is there any other ways to do this in angular2-dart directly?

Here is [working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/LYTXmY9Fwm8LwumICWDT?p=preview) which is based on rxjs Subject lib.

```
<h1>{{componentTitle}}<h1>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Dart you use `Stream` and `StreamController` instead of `Observable` and `Subject`:

```
@Injectable()
export class RouteNames{
  StreamController<String> _nameController = new StreamController<String>();
  String get name => _nameController.stream;

  void newName(String name) => _nameController.add(name);
}
```

then you can subscribe like:

```
AppComponent(this._routeNames){
  _routeNames.name.listen((n) => this.routeName = n);
}
```

and updates can be sent like:

```
HeroListComponent(
  this._service,
  this._router,
  this._routeParams,
  this._routeNames:RouteNames){
    this._selectedId = +routeParams.get('id');
     _routeNames.newName('Heroes');
}
```

To support multiple subscribers you need to make the stream a broadcaststream:

```
@Injectable()
export class RouteNames{
  StreamController<String> _nameController = new StreamController<String>.broadcast();

  public get name => _nameController.stream;

  newName(String name) => _nameController.add(name);
}
```